# How can I read the error content outputs of mysql command executed from python

Tags: python, mysql, windows, cmd

`bash_fc = rf"mysql -u {source_user_name} -h {source_ipv4_addr} --password={source_db_password}"`

**When I use the following functions for the above command,**

```
from subprocess import PIPE,run
def cons_r(cmd):
  response = run(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
  return response.stdout
```

```
response = os.popen(bash_fc)
```

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: Unknown OS character set 'cp857'.
mysql: Switching to the default character set 'utf8mb4'.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'pc.mshome.net' (using password: YES)

I can't read the output, is there a method you know of so I can read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This change fixed the problem**

```
from subprocess import PIPE, run, STDOUT
def cons_r(cmd):
  response = run(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
  return response.stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read errors from standard error

```
import subprocess as sp

ret = sp.run(['ls', '*.bad'], stderr=sp.PIPE,
             stdout=sp.PIPE, shell=True, encoding="cp857")

if ret.returncode == 0:
    print(ret.stdout)
else:
    print(ret.stderr)
```

Comment: `stderr=sp.PIPE` When the parameter is `PIPE`, we cannot read the error outputs. It's supposed to be `stderr=sp.STDOUT`, thanks for the reply.

Comment: I heve verified that peace of code before show to you and it works with and without errors. maybe mysql works in some strange way.